# Function to bound a probability away from 0 and 1

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, special-functions

I'm writing a statistical model in which I want to apply a convex penalty to a model-derived probability, call it p. There is also a known constant, c. For the solution to the statistical model to have desirable properties, I would like this penalty function, F(p), to have the following properties:

1. F(0)= $\infty$
2. F(1)= $\infty$
3. F(p) > F(c) $\forall p \neq c$.
4. F is convex in p

Thus, the penalty is minimized when p equals the known constant c. So far, the best I have been able to come up with is

$$ F(p) = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{1-p}$$

but this, of course, does not have a minimum at c. Note that I only need the function to be defined for $p \in [0,1]$. The simpler the function the better. If it involves logarithms or exponentials, that is especially nice because of the ease of computing derivatives with respect to p.

Comment: $F(p) = \frac{(p-c)^2}{p} + \frac{(p-c)^2}{1-p}$

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but $F_n(x)=\exp \left ( n \left ( x \ln \left ( \frac{x}{c} \right ) + (1-x) \ln \left ( \frac{1-x}{1-c} \right ) \right ) \right )$ for large $n$ "essentially" achieve what you want, and have a meaning in probability theory.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks, that's kind of what I had in mind. Do you know if functions of the form d(p,c)/p + d(p,c)/(1-p) for some metric d are the only functions with the properties I'm looking for?

Comment: @Ian You're right that this achieves what I want for large n. What is the meaning in probability theory?

Comment: Note that, for $a,b \geq 1$ with $a \neq b$, $\frac{a(p-c)^2}{p} + \frac{b(p-c)^2}{1-p}$ also works, and these two numerators are not one metric function.  So, no, not all such functions are of the form you write.

Comment: You do not need to add the terms driving to $\infty$ - multiplication works too as in  you could use $\frac{(p-c)^2}{p(1-p)}$

Comment: @Henry Thanks, this is more elegant.